# SQL Query - Count() and Inner Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to use an inner join to list the student ID, name, and total number of timetabled hours the student has per week, when the student has more than 4 hours per week.

I have three tables required here, student, studentReg and roomBooking as follows

```
 student

 id | fname | surname | courseCode

studentReg

sID | modCode

roomBooking

bookingID | roomCode | moduleCode | dayReq | timeReq | semester | classSize
```

The SQL query I have so far is

```
 SELECT COUNT(moduleCode) AS [Lecture Hours],
 id, fname, surname
 FROM (student INNER JOIN studentReg ON student.id = studentReg.sID
        INNER JOIN roomBooking ON studentReg.modCode = roomBooking.moduleCode)
 HAVING COUNT (moduleCode) > 4;
```

and when I try to run this, I get "syntax error in expression"

Can anyone help me as to what the problem is?

Comment: what syntax error are you getting??

Comment: @CodeLღver "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'student.id = studentReg.sID INNER JOIN roomBooking ON studentReg.modCode = roomBooking.moduleCod'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never sure with nested join in ms access, but I would try something like that

```
SELECT COUNT(moduleCode) AS [Lecture Hours],
 id, fname, surname
 FROM student 
 INNER JOIN (studentReg 
        INNER JOIN roomBooking ON studentReg.modCode = roomBooking.moduleCode)
        ON student.id = studentReg.sID
 GROUP BY id, fname, surname
 HAVING COUNT (moduleCode) > 4
```

or maybe

```
SELECT COUNT(moduleCode) AS [Lecture Hours],
 id, fname, surname
 FROM (student INNER JOIN studentReg ON student.id = studentReg.sID)
        INNER JOIN roomBooking ON studentReg.modCode = roomBooking.moduleCode
 GROUP BY id, fname, surname
 HAVING COUNT (moduleCode) > 4;
```

Comment: I am 99% sure it is the 2nd query. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @GarethD yup, a feed-back from OP would be nice ;)